# Polynomial algorithm for a special ILP problem

Tags: linear-programming, computational-complexity, set-covering

Given the following problem:

\begin{align} 
& z=\min \sum_{ij} x_{ij}\\
\text{s.t.} & \quad \sum_i d_{ij} x_{ij} \ge s_j, \quad \forall j \tag1 \\
& \quad \sum_j x_{ij} \le 1, \quad \forall i \tag2 \\
& \quad x_{ij} \in \left\{0, 1\right\}, \quad \forall i,j \tag3 \\
\end{align}

with known $d_{ij}, s_j$, is there an algorithm that solves it in polinomial time? If not, is there an approximate one?

Comment: It seems to me that it should be equivalent to a matching problem in bipartite graphs, where the problem is to minimize the number of edges with respect to the constraints.

Comment: I first thought it might be a flow in a bipartite graph, but constraint (1) is the problem; either you take $d_{ij}$ entirely on arc $(i,j)$, or nothing, and you cannot control this in a flow

Comment: I think this looks somewhat similar to an exact cover problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us get some additional insights by assuming $d_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$ and interpreting the data as a directed graph. For now we assume the number of $i$'s and $j$'s is the same, but I don't think it will be difficult to generalize that assumption. We say there is an arc from $i$ to $j$ iff $d_{ij} \neq 0$. Now for each vertex $j$ where $s_j \neq 0$, we have to select at least $\lceil s_j \rceil$ incoming arcs. Selecting an arcs that ends in $j$ can only help to cover the particular constraint of $j$, and thus if we ignore Constraints $(2)$, variables only occur in a single constraint and the optimal objective would be $\sum_{j} \lceil s_j \rceil $.

If we do consider Constraints $(2)$, we get the constraint that for every vertex at most one outgoing arc can be selected. This problem can be formulated as a min-cost flow with demands. Construct a flow graph with a source and a sink, and two intermediate layers with nodes for indices $i$ and $j$. From the source to each $i$, add an arc with capacity $1$ to impose Constraints $(2)$ and give them costs $1$ to represent the objective function. From each $i$ to $j$ add an arc with capacity $1$ and costs zero iff $d_{ij} = 1$. Finally, add arcs from $j$ to the sink with demand $s_j$ and costs zero. Computing a min-cost flow that adheres to the demands gives you an optimal solution in polynomial time for this special case.

As [Luke599999](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/4412/1047) pointed out, for the general case you can easily reduce a subset sum problem to this problem, which makes it weakly NP-hard. In fact, you can even reduce from 3-Partition to prove it is strongly NP-hard. Take a 3-partition instance where $k$ partitions of size $B$ must be constructed and each number $n_i$ is between $\frac{B}{4}$ and $\frac{B}{2}$ and all numbers add up to $kB$. Define $k$ entries $s_j = B$ for each partition that must be constructed, and define $d_{ij} = n_i$ for each number $i$. Constraints $(2)$ enforces that every number will be used at most once, and Constraints $(1)$ enforce that each partition is at least $B$. Now the only feasible solution would correspond to a valid 3-partition.

In practice, it should not be too difficult to construct a useful lower bound for your problem. For each of the Constraints $(2)$, solve a subset sum problem using dynamic programming to determine the minimum number of arcs you must select to fulfill that constraint. This is a pseudo-polynomial algorithm which can be solved fast in practice if your numbers are small. If you sum this up over all these constraints you get a lower bound on the number of arcs that must be selected and thus of the objective value. Constraints $(2)$ gives you a simple upper bound: you can never select more arcs than the number of nodes.

As it is NP-hard to determine whether an instance is feasible, any approximation that guarantees to find a feasible solution is also NP-hard. The special case with $d_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$ is solvable in polynomial time. Perhaps other special cases can be solved in polynomial time, but it will require you to exploit additional structure of your input data.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is NP-hard because it can be used to solve the subset-sum problem:

Subset-sum: given a set of numbers $a_k\forall k\in K$ and a special number $b$ is there a subset of numbers $K' \subset K$ such that $\sum_ {k\in K'} a_k =b$

Reduction: let $j \in \{1,2\}$, and $s_1=b$ $d_{k,j} = a_k \forall k,j$ and $s_2=\sum_i a_i - b$

I don't know of any approximation algorithms.